# Plot line and polyshape - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a polygon and a line using the code below but the line does not start from 0, 0. Any idea why?

Code:

```
close all;
clear;
clc;

xLine(1) = 0;
yLine(1) = 0;
xLine(2) = -2;
yLine(2) = -2; 
lineseg = [xLine(1), yLine(1); xLine(2), yLine(2)];

P = [0 0; 1 1; 1 0; 0 1; 0 0];
pgon = polyshape(P) 

plot(lineseg);
hold on;
plot(pgon);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `plot`

> `plot(Y)` creates a 2-D line plot of the data in Y **versus the index of each value.**
>
> [...]
>
> If Y is a matrix, then the plot function plots the columns of Y versus their row number. The x-axis scale ranges from 1 to the number of rows in Y.

So you are plotting the row numbers (`[1 2]`) against the values in each row, in this case twice but the columns of `lineseg` are equivalent so you don't see that.

You probably want to instead use something like

```
plot( lineseg(:,1), lineseg(:,2) );
```

i.e. use the `plot(X,Y)` form of the `plot` function